# how to solve this first order nonlinear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm reading nonlinear control systems book. The author provides this example
$$
\dot{x} = r + x^2, \quad r < 0.
$$
I would like to compute the analytical solution for the proceeding ODE. My attempt is

$$
\begin{align}
\frac{dx}{dt} &= r + x^2 \\
\frac{dx}{r+x^2} &= dt \\
\int^{x(t)}_{x_0} \frac{1}{r+x^2} dx &= \int^{t}_{t_0} d\tau \\
\frac{\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{r}}\right)}{\sqrt{r}} \Big|^{x(t)}_{x_0} &= (t-t_0)
\end{align}
$$

Now the problem with the assumption that $r<0$, how I can handle the substitution for the left side? I need to reach the final step where $x(t)$ is solely in the left side.

Comment: Substitute $u = \frac{x}{\sqrt{-r}}$. You'll get an inverse *hyperbolic* tangent.

Comment: So it is $x^2 - a^2$ at the bottom. Could use partial fractions.

Comment: @Christoph, why did you put the minus ? Also, how to handle the square root of negative number?

Comment: @ArcticChar, what is $a$?

Comment: If $r<0$ you have $-r>0$, so you can take the square root of that.

Comment: $-a^2=r$, so $a$ is the square root of the positive number $-r$.

Comment: @Christoph, if I get an inverse hyperbolic tangent, should I use $\tan^{-1}(u) = \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1+u}{1-u}\right)$ and then I proceed?

Comment: The expression that you wrote down is wrong, but ultimately it is a matter of preference here whether you want to go to exponential or hyperbolic functions. Aleksas Domarkas has already shown you the solution in terms of exponential functions. Alternatively, the solution may be written using $\tanh$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $r=-a^2$. Then
$$\int\frac{dx}{x^2-a^2}=\int dt$$
$$-\frac{\log{\left( x+a\right) }-\log{\left( x-a\right) }}{2 a}=t+c$$
Take $c=\frac{\log C}{2a}$.
$$\log{\left( \frac{x-a}{C\, \left( x+a\right) }\right) }=2 a t,$$
$$\frac{x-a}{x+a}=C\, {{e}^{2 a t}}.$$
General solution is
$$x=\frac{a(1+Ce^{2at})}{1-Ce^{2at}}.$$

Answer (score 5):

Let us consider

$$\dot x=x^2-1$$ for convenience.

When $|x|<1$, we solve the separable equation with

$$\frac{dx}{1-x^2}=-dt$$ and

$$\text{artanh }x-\text{artanh }x_0=t_0-t,$$

i.e.

$$x=\tanh(t_0-t+\text{artanh }x_0).$$

When $|x|>1$, we solve with

$$\text{arcoth }x-\text{arcoth }x_0=t_0-t,$$

i.e.

$$x=\coth(t_0-t+\text{arcoth }x_0).$$

Notice that this solution has a vertical asymptote at $t=t_0+\text{arcoth }x_0$.

Finally, $x=\pm1$ are two valid solutions.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

Solve it as Riccati equation by setting $x=-\frac{u'}{u}$. Then
$$
u''-a^2u=0
$$
has the solution $u(t)=Ce^{at}+De^{-at}$ and thus
$$
y(x)=-a\frac{Ce^{at}-De^{-at}}{Ce^{at}+De^{-at}}
$$
with some redundancy in the parameter pair $(C,D)$.

Answer (score 0):

We use separation of variables to solve the ODE $\dot{x} = r + x^2$, $r < 0$:

1. We first find the constant solutions $x \equiv \pm \sqrt{-r}$. In the following steps we shall assume $r+x^2 \not \equiv 0$.
2. We use the Leibniz notation and we separate the variables: $\frac{dx}{dt} = r + x^2$, $\frac{1}{r+x^2} dx = dt$.
3. We integrate on both sides: $\int \frac{1}{r+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int 1 \, \mathrm{d}t$.
4. We solve the integral on the left-hand side using the substitution $x = \sqrt{-r} u$, $dx = \sqrt{-r} du$:
   \begin{eqnarray}
   \int \frac{1}{r+x^2} \, \mathrm{d}x &=& \int \frac{1}{r-ru^2} \sqrt{-r} \, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{\sqrt{-r}}{r} \int \frac{1}{1-u^2} \, \mathrm{d}u = \frac{\sqrt{-r}}{r} \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
   \operatorname{artanh}(u) + \tilde{C}, & |u| < 1\\
   \operatorname{arcoth}(u) + \tilde{C}, & |u| > 1
   \end{array}
   \right.\\
   &=& \frac{\sqrt{-r}}{r} \left\{ \begin{array}{ll}
   \operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{-r}}\right) + \tilde{C}, & |x| < \sqrt{-r}\\
   \operatorname{arcoth}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{-r}}\right) + \tilde{C}, & |x| > \sqrt{-r}
   \end{array}
   \right., \quad \tilde{C} \in \mathbb{R}.
   \end{eqnarray}

Thus we now obtain the nonlinear equations
\begin{eqnarray}
\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{-r}}\right) = C -\sqrt{-r} t, \quad |x| < \sqrt{-r},\\
\operatorname{arcoth}\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{-r}}\right) = C -\sqrt{-r} t, \quad |x| > \sqrt{-r},
\end{eqnarray}
with a constant $C \in \mathbb{R}$.

Finally, we obtain 4 possible solutions of the ODE, depending on the initial value $x(t_0) = x_0 \in \mathbb{R}$:
\begin{eqnarray}
x(t) &=& \sqrt{-r} \coth\left(\operatorname{arcoth}\left(\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{-r}}\right)-\sqrt{-r}(t-t_0)\right), \quad |x_0| > \sqrt{-r},\\
x(t) &=& -\sqrt{-r}, \quad x_0 = -\sqrt{-r},\\
x(t) &=& \sqrt{-r}, \quad x_0 = \sqrt{-r},\\
x(t) &=& \sqrt{-r} \tanh\left(\operatorname{artanh}\left(\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{-r}}\right)-\sqrt{-r}(t-t_0) \right), \quad |x_0| < \sqrt{-r}.
\end{eqnarray}